# linux PS1 - display branch name only inside a git repo

Tags: git, bash, ps1

After searching the net, I found that one can display the git branch name with the PS1 with below

```
PS1="$(__git_ps1 ) "
```

While this is working fine, and it display the branch name in PS1 prompt. But it is displayed where-ever I navigate, even outside the git-checked-out-repo.

I would like to display the branch name only if I am under a git tracked folder/repo. Any way to achieve this? Searching SO and net didn't pop-up helpful links in this respect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to defer execution of `$(__git_ps1)` until `PS1` is actually displayed. Use single quotes:

```
PS1='$(__git_ps1)'
```

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks a lot. I didn't knew this. Would it be possible for you to provide some link to any bash documentation that explain the usage of quotes?

Comment: However, aside from quoting, this is also special behavior of `PS1` (and other prompt values). The value of the variable isn't simply displayed as-is; it undergoes a full round of evaluation. Note that your prompt will look different than the output of `echo "$PS1"`.

Comment: Hi chepner, please see my related question on this topic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125564/how-to-display-git-branch-in-ps1-with-other-output

Comment: Hi Chepner, please can you show me a way to display additional info like datetime along with git branch. It would be really helpful. I'll try rest of the part. Sorry for pestering.. :(