# How to display git branch in PS1 with other output?

Tags: git, bash, ps1

I got to display just the branch name in the PS1 if I am in a git repo
[linux PS1 - display branch name only inside a git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970203/linux-ps1-display-branch-name-only-inside-a-git-repo), but I am not able to get it integrated with my earlier PS1, which is

```
 PS1="[\D{%F} \@] \u /\W $ "
```

this displays, datetime + username

```
 [2015-08-20 11:38 PM] mtk
```

I tried

```
PS1="[\D{%F} \@] \u /\W $(__git_ps1) $ "
```

but, i get error

```
__git_ps1: command not found
<empty PS1>
```

Any way to get git branch name along with earlier details that my PS1 used to output?

EDIT:
I also tried

```
 PS1="[\D{%F} \@] \u /\W '$(__git_ps1)' $ "
```

but, this gives empty quotes always, even inside a git repo.

The question is different from that one. I was to display time and date + git branch (if its inside a repo).

Comment: Single quotes on the assignment. You need to delay the expansion until `PS1` is evaluated for each prompt.

Comment: There's really no difference between this question and your previous one.

Comment: @Etan It's different. I am not able to integrate other PS1 features with $(__git_ps1)

Comment: Single quotes around the *entire* assignment. You don't want it being evaluated then. `PS1='....'`

Comment: Thanks, i am able to do it with single quotes..

Answer (score 0):

```
PS1="[\D{%F} \@] \u /\W \$(__git_ps1) $ "
```

or

```
PS1='[\D{%F} \@] \u /\W $(__git_ps1) $ '
```

You must escape the `$` in order to be executed each time, not only once. You can do so by using single quotes or escaping it with a `\`.